# CSS styles isn't working with .htaccess redirects

Tags: php, html, css, apache, .htaccess

I started creating a website and here's the trouble:
I'm using `.htaccess` rules

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ php/mvc.php?htTargUrl=$1 [QSA,L,B,BNP,NC]
```

mvc.php processes all requests. If the link starts with "/assets/..." then mvc.php includes real file

```
if(file_exists($path) && !is_dir($path)){
    include($path);
} else {
    echo 'File does not exist <br>';
}
```

If I open `amelia.lc/assets/css/style.css/` - I'll see the style.css file
If I open `amelia.lc/assets/img/header/main-logo.png` - I'll see image code (�ա and any other symbols)

If I add `<img href="assets/img/header/main-logo.png">` to my website - I will see an image
But if I add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css/">` - style won't work

Comment: you won't get proper MIME type with include(), try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067132/php-include-proper-mime-types

Comment: "style won't work" - what is the response sent to the browser? `href="assets/css/style.css/"` - Are you removing the trailing slash at some point? Using _relative_ paths to your assets is going to be problematic if you have pages with URL-paths outside the document root.